# How stop slider on mouse over in Cslider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I use Cslider in my html website , how can i stop slider on mouse over ?

this is jQuery codes of Cslider >

[jquery.cslider.js](http://keyhan-plastic.ir/newtemp/js/jquery.cslider.js)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To make it pause on hover add these lines to the _loadEvents function:**

```
this.$slides.on({
mouseenter: function(){
if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
}
},
mouseleave: function(){
var default_interval = _self.options.interval;
if(_self.options.autoplay ) {
_self.options.interval = 500;
_self._startSlideshow();
_self.options.interval = default_interval;
}
}
});
```

Assuming you're using [Parallax Content Slider](http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/)

Comment: thx , but how can i put this there ? after
   `// load the events
   this._loadEvents();` ? or between parentheses ?

Comment: add after `_loadEvents   : function() {
   
   var _self = this;`

Comment: @Moriuzx Please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you.